# For loop with an argument based range

Tags: bash, for-loop, printf

I want to run certain actions on a group of lexicographically named files (01-09 before 10). I have to use a rather old version of FreeBSD (7.3), so I can't use yummies like `echo {01..30}` or `seq -w 1 30`.

The only working solution I found is `printf "%02d " {1..30}`. However, I can't figure out why can't I use `$1` and `$2` instead of `1` and `30`. When I run my script (`bash ~/myscript.sh 1 30`) printf says `{1..30}: invalid number`

AFAIK, variables in bash are typeless, so how can't printf accept an integer argument as an integer?

Comment: It's not a problem with what printf will/won't accept at all. It's a problem because parameter expansions haven't taken place yet when brace expansion occurs.

Comment: This is alluded to by BashPitfalls #33: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D -- the links there might be helpful to better understanding what's going on when a command is run.

Comment: (by the way, it _is_ possible to flag a variable as containing an integer; while there's very little reason to ever do so, there actually _is_ some amount of type data stored).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it!

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSD-only iteration method    
#for day in `jot $1 $2`
for ((day=$1; day<$2; day++))
do
    echo $(printf %02d $day)
done
```

I initially wanted to use the cycle iterator as a "day" in file names, but now I see that in my exact case it's easier to iterate through normal numbers (1,2,3 etc.) and process them into lexicographical ones inside the loop. While using `jot`, remember that `$1` is the numbers amount, and the `$2` is the starting point.

Comment: What's `jot`? It's not a POSIX-standard command or a bash builtin.

Comment: Assuming it just prints a series of numbers starting at its first argument and ending just before its second argument, the way that works anywhere bash is installed would be `for ((day=$1; day<$2; day++))`.

Comment: (hmm -- appears to be a BSDism; available on OS X, but not on the Linux flavors I've poked at... which is to say that by using it, you're reducing your script's portability).

Comment: `jot` is the (don't ask me how it happened so) FreeBSD version of `seq`. It's works actually same, e.g. I use `joe` instead of `nano`, not because I hate `nano`, it's just not installed, and `joe` does exact same thing. There is a slight syntax difference between `jot` and `seq`, however, I've added a bit of description on what you should pass to `jot`

Comment: Why the `echo $(printf ...)` vs just `printf ...`? Adds the overhead of a subshell without benefit; if you want a trailing newline, put a `; echo` on the end -- much more efficient than `fork()`ing to start a subshell, `read`ing its output, `wait`ing for it to close, string-splitting and glob-expanding that output and setting it up as arguments to `echo`.

Comment: I see you sir are **quite pedantic**, but I'm using that to get filenames, not to actually print it, and added an `echo` only to check if I'm doing everything right. Now leave me alone, please

Comment: `printf` prints to stdout, just the same as `echo` does. Adding the echo "checks" *absolutely nothing* that `printf` alone would not. (And with that, I've said all I mean to say, and am happy to honor your request).

Answer (score 1):

Bash supports C-style for loops:

```
s=1
e=30
for i in ((i=s; i<e; i++)); do printf "%02d " "$i"; done
```

The syntax you attempted doesn't work because brace expansion happens *before* parameter expansion, so when the shell tries to expand `{$1..$2}`, it's still *literally* `{$1..$2}`, not `{1..30}`.

---

The answer given by @Kent works because `eval` goes back to the beginning of the parsing process. I tend to suggest avoiding making habitual use of it, as [`eval` can introduce hard-to-recognize bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) -- if your command were whitelisted to be run by `sudo` and `$1` were, say, `'$(rm -rf /; echo 1)'`, the C-style-for-loop example would safely fail, and the eval example... not so much.

Granted, 95% of the scripts you write may not be accessible to folks executing privilege escalation attacks, but the remaining 5% can really ruin one's day; following good practices 100% of the time avoids being in sloppy habits.

---

Thus, if one *really* wants to pass a range of numbers to a single command, the safe thing is to collect them in an array:

```
a=( )
for i in ((i=s; i<e; i++)); do a+=( "$i" ); done
printf "%02d " "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
s=1
e=30
printf "%02d "  $(eval echo {$s..$e})
```